# Intercept serial port data in Delphi

Tags: delphi, gps, serial-port, sniffer

I know how to comunicate over serial port using TComPort, but I'd like to view the data going in and out a virtual (USB<=>RSR232) COM port without interupting the transmition and (obviously) opening the port. To be precise I want to see the GPS data from the USB GPS receiver.
The thing is that I need to apps using the same data at the same time. My Delphi app and the navigation software. The alternative would be to have the decent PC navigation software with Europe maps (open street map would also be fine, but can't find any decent car navigation software) that has good API whci can return the GPS position.

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Thanks!
G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) device driver in conjunction with hub4com.

From [documentation](http://com0com.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/com0com/hub4com/ReadMe.txt?revision=RELEASED):

> In conjunction with the com0com driver the hub4com allows to
>
> - handle data and signals from a single real serial device by a number of
>     different applications. For example, several applications can share data
>     from one GPS device;

Example:

> GPS hub
>
> ---
>
> You have a GPS device that connected to your computer via a physical COM1
>   port and you'd like to handle its data by two GPS applications. You can
>   do it this way:
>
> 1. With the com0com's Setup Command Prompt create COM5<->CNCB0 and
>       COM6<->CNCB1 virtual COM port pairs (see com0com's ReadMe.txt for
>       more info). For example:
>
>    ```
>    command> install 0 PortName=COM5 -
>    command> install 1 PortName=COM6 -
>    ```
> 2. Start the hub4com.exe on COM1, CNCB0 and CNCB1 ports:
>
>    ```
>    hub4com \\.\COM1 \\.\CNCB0 \\.\CNCB1
>    ```
>
>    It will send data received from COM1 port to CNCB0 and CNCB1 ports
>       and it will send data received from CNCB0 port to COM1 port.
> 3. Start the GPS applications on COM5 and COM6 ports.

Comment: Yes,this seems to be the most reasonable to integrate into my app as using 3rd party apps just logging serial data would require working with files or using winAPI to capture data. Now I only need to find a way to make unatended/silent instalation and configuration together with my app.

Comment: @GrzesiekMy take a look at http://www.bermione.be/technology/handle-gps-data-by-two-gps-apps-simultaneously/ for an example of setting it up for silent installation, configuration and startup.

Comment: It should solve my issue, however I do wonder if there's a way of doing it all directly from within the Delphi code? Well, there must be, but how? How to write a delphi serial port sniffer should be the question? Or should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: Yes, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PortMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896644.aspx) utility by Mark Russinovich

Comment: I recently used PortMon to capture RS-232 data from a power supply in a Delphi application we were using. By seeing what the suppliers sample program was sending to the power supply, we were able to emulate the commands in our Delphi application. Works well.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Advanced Serial Port Monitor can monitor USB COM port too and works on Windows 7,8 **64 bit**.

http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-port-monitor.htm

Note: you should use the SPY mode in ASPM.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.